# PhoneGap Facebook Connect Plugin on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I was wondering if any succeeded with the instructions at : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin ?

My environment is as follows:
1) xcode: Version 4.5.1 (4G1004)
2) Phonegap: 2.5
3) Macbook Pro 64bit.
4) Facebook SDK 3.2
5) Target build is iOS5 ( tried 6 but also failed )

After following the instructions at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin for iOS, my build failed.

And the error message is:

```
ld: 379 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

can anyone point me as to how to fix this error ?

any online tutorials, or step by step instructions will be great too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issues, and fixed it by following this on Github : https://github.com/ghn/phonegap-facebook-plugin/commit/83d41c1b3e999f11333ff7da89918ff6e58bf72f

#### Add the Cordova Facebook Plugin:

1. Locate the **plugins** section of your Project Navigator and create a group "ios". Make sure it is added as a "group" (yellow folder)
2. From the **Cordova Facebook Plugin** folder copy FacebookConnectPlugin.h and 
   FacebookConnectPlugin.m from the **src** folder into the new group "ios".
3. Find the `config.xml` file in the project navigator and add a new entry as a child to the plugin tag:

   - `< plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />`

You have to create an ios folder into the plugins directory. And ensure FacebookConnectPlugin.h and FacebookConnectPlugin.m are removed from plugins directory.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes from including both a compiled library (as a framework in the project or as a build target in the "Build Phases" project properties tab) and the .m source files that generate it.

Some tutorials tell you to include the FacebookSDKResources.bundle frameworks and some tell you to copy the source files in Plugins/ios/facebook. If you do both you'll get this error.